# Who do I call, roofer or plumber?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, leak, roof

Last fall, I noticed my first floor kitchen had a leak that dripped down through the lighting fixture. This happened during a pretty strong rainfall. There is a bathroom above it but it had not been used in a few days. This then happened two more times, both again during rainstorms. No leaks all winter.

I want to get it looked at before it happens again. Should I call a roofer or a plumber?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Roofer would be the initial guess. One has to guess that because the leak is seen during a storm.

Even though the leak may be coming in around the vent stack pipe for the bathroom it is still a roofers skill to properly seal a leak like that.

Comment: Yup, what he says. I had a leak at my first floor ceiling and I thought it was my daughter not closing the shower curtain well enough and water seeping around the plate and through a drilled hole for a wire or something. Later, I found the water was coming in around a bad boot around a vent through the roof. The rainwater followed the pipe through the second floor, not even showing up on the second floor ceiling and dripped off an elbow to show at the first floor ceiling

Comment: You were right. Had a crack in a boot in the roof.